# javascript: default collapsing function for complex table not works

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a default collapsing effect like below, instead expanding everything:

[image]

After clicking "Parameter 1", it will also have the default effect like below:

[image]

The current "$('#problematicRowspan').hide();" is not working yet. Please kindly help, thanks in advance.

**JS**

```
$('.P1').click(function() {
  $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value) {
    return value == '-' ? '+' : '-'
  });
  $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(.P2)').slideToggle(100, function() {});
});

$('.Sub-parameter-1').click(function() {
  $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value) {
    return value == '-' ? '+' : '-'
  });
  $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(.Sub-parameter-2)').slideToggle(100, function() {});
  var rows = parseInt($('#problematicRowspan').attr('rowspan'));
  if(rows == 4) {
     rows-=2;
     $('#problematicRowspan').hide();   //here not works
  }
  else {
    rows+=2;
    $('#problematicRowspan').show();      //here not works
  }
  $('#problematicRowspan').attr('rowspan', rows);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="7">Summary </td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div align="center">1 st level</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="P1"><span>-</span>Parameter 1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="problematicRowspan" rowspan="4">L1</td>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="Sub-parameter-1"><span>-</span>Sub parameter (1)</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>L2</td>
    <td>description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>L2</td>
    <td>description1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="Sub-parameter-2"><span>-</span>Sub parameter (2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="P2">Parameter 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7tvgnw22/

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

LIke this

```
var _this = $(this);

 _this.closest("#problematicRowspan").hide();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/e2pbhj20/)**</kbd>

Comment: ,thanks, but why in DEMO, it still expands everything in default?

Comment: that becuase you didn't put any code for collapse on page load or document load. @Héléna . you have putted collapse and expand for click only